# Can't get 16 bit assembly program to jump to 0x1000:0x0000

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader

I know I succeed in writing my code to that address using `int 13h` because I can see it at that memory location. What I can't do is jump there.

I put `0x1000` (three zeros there) into `es` and `0x0000` into `bx` and I know that `[es:bx]` means the address calculated by `(es * 0x10) + bx` which does equal `0x10000` (four zeros there). But `eip`, the instruction pointer, never does go there.

I've tried `jmp [es:bx]`, `jmp 0x1000:0x0000`, and a bunch of other permutations that `NASM` doesn't even accept.

My boot loader as it currently is (which still isn't working) is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J2vNReGoeXz7PoBzYHg3bwNpXeeOKkSmS3rmmd_yxmY/edit). I booted it up in Qemu and did a memsave on the first 50 bytes at `0x10000`, opened it up with tweak, and saw my "kernel" code there (simple . But `EIP` still refuses to be `0x10000`, or reach it and then hang where I want it, is what I mean). Full images of the situation [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pjeP_NXKeuZQb8zmeLaMlWyh5YqWD34jZIQcxBBzPf0/edit)

Comment: Edit my bad you provided the code.

Comment: Setting EIP in a 16-bit program is going to be difficult, that's a 32-bit register.  The value of IP will be 0 after the jump.

Comment: @Pete - `jmp [es:bx]` would be an indirect jump to the address stored at `[es:bx]`. However, `jmp seg:offset` or `jmp far seg:offset` should work. And, like Hans says, at 0x1000:0 you would have `CS=0x1000` and `IP=0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A far jump can't use use a memory location just for the segment. Here are several ways you can do it:

1) simple hardcoded address for both segment and offset.

```
jmp 0x1000:0
```

2) indirect jump using a full address:

```
entry dw 0x0000 ; offset
      dw 0x1000 ; segment

jmp far dword ptr [entry] ; far jump (syntax might differ)
```

3) a far return

```
push SYSADDR ; segment
push 0       ; offset
retf         ; far return
```

A common trick used in DOS time was patching the intruction:

```
  mov ax, SYSADDR
  mov word ptr [myjump+3], ax
myjump:
  jmp 0x0000:0x0000
```

or using a part of it as a variable:

```
myjump:
  db 0xEA           ; far jmp opcode 
  dw 0x0000         ; offset part
  SYSADDR dw 0x1000 ; segment part
```

Disclaimer: all of the aboves come from memory and I might have gotten some parts wrong (e.g. the order of segment/offset was very confusing).

Comment: Fixed code. Segment is in the high address. Your disclaimer was correct!

Comment: Patching the instruction as you did in the fourth example wouldn't work reliably on older DOS-era CPUs because the JMP instruction could be in the prefetch buffer when you attempt to modify it.  You need to put a control transfer instruction in between the modification and the instruction being modified to clear the prefetch queue. eg. `mov word ptr [myjump+3], ax` `jmp myjump`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do exactly what you're trying. Here's an example that does the same thing, presumably for the same reason:

```
; http://www.free2code.net/tutorials/view/writing_your_own_operating_system-12/page1.html
...
mov bx,0x1000  ;Es and Bx put together are where to load the program too 
               ; (see jmp x1000:0x00)
mov es,bx
mov bx,0x00
int 13h        ;Int 13 is all functions for disks
...
```